# Erro ao compilar código utilizando a lib de conversão MP3 libmp3lame.a

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone

Alguém poderia me ajudar, estou com um problema ao rodar meu app no Iphone 6 eu utilizo uma biblioteca para converter audio em mp3 chamada de **libmp3lame.a**, mas não consigo compilar, segue o warning.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Abound/Desktop/Projeto Sistema da Igreja/App/AppIgreja/AppIgreja/GravaAudio/libmp3lame.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/Abound/Desktop/Projeto Sistema da Igreja/App/AppIgreja/AppIgreja/GravaAudio/libmp3lame.a (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_lame_close", referenced from:
   -[CorrenteOracoes toMp3] in CorrenteOracoes.o
"_lame_encode_buffer_interleaved", referenced from:
  -[CorrenteOracoes toMp3] in CorrenteOracoes.o
"_lame_encode_flush", referenced from:
  -[CorrenteOracoes toMp3] in CorrenteOracoes.o
"_lame_init", referenced from:
  -[CorrenteOracoes toMp3] in CorrenteOracoes.o
"_lame_init_params", referenced from:
  -[CorrenteOracoes toMp3] in CorrenteOracoes.o
"_lame_set_VBR", referenced from:
  -[CorrenteOracoes toMp3] in CorrenteOracoes.o
"_lame_set_in_samplerate", referenced from:
  -[CorrenteOracoes toMp3] in CorrenteOracoes.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: O erro está falando que a versão do **libmp3lame.a** não está usando arquitetura x86_64. Tente baixar uma nova versão que suporta essa arquitetura [neste repositório](https://github.com/ihsanhusnul/libmp3lame-ios), ou gerar uma nova lib você mesmo seguindo [esses passos](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27244844/1873427).

Answer (score 0):

Sim, como bem comentou iTSangar, você só precisa recompilar a biblioteca`libmp3lame` com suporte para arquitetura **x86_4**, que nada mais é do que o Simulador do iOS (Ou você está usando a biblioteca para um programa Desktop?). Caso você esteja usando um aparelho, tal como um iPhone ou iPad, o `libmp3lame` funcionará normalmente, sem erros de compilação.

Coincidentemente nós também mantemos um projeto de uma Igreja para iOS, o qual necessita enviar gravações feitas em **.mp3** para serem usadas como testemunhos, daí a necessidade de usarmos o `libmp3lame`.

Se precisar de ajuda para compilar o `libmp3lame` para ser usado no Simulador, por favor edite a sua resposta para podermos ajudá-lo mais especificamente.